# Batch renaming images, removing part after

Tags: file, powershell, renaming

I have a directory with around 7000 images, named with the format, X_Y, where X is a variable length number and Y is a variable length string.

I want an easy way, using maybe DOS or powershell, to rename all these files and remove the '_Y' part, so that all the images are named X.

Easy and quick methods would be appreciated :D

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```
$recurse = $false

Get-ChildItem "C:\image\folder" -Recurse:$recurse `
  | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match '^(\d+)_.+(\..*?)$' } `
  | % { Rename-Item $_.FullName ($matches[1]+$matches[2]) }
```

Set `$recurse = $true` if you want to recurse into subfolders.

Comment: Copy/paste it into a PowerShell window. Make sure you adjust the path first.

Comment: It isnt working for me. I wrote all you said but it just gives >> on another line and nothing happens.

Comment: hit enter again. The empty line will tell powershell that you wrote all your script and begin execution.